# php / mysql - select id from one table excepting ids which are in another table

Tags: php, mysql

for example i have 2 tables: 
1 . **users**:

```
id     Name
1       Mike
2       Adam
3       Tom
4       John
5       Andy
6       Ray
```

2 . **visits**:

```
userID     date
1           ...
3           ...
6           ...
```

i want to make a page which can be visited once in 12 hours, when user visits that page his id is included in database ( visits ), how i can select all users ( from  database **users**) excepting users who visited page in <= 12 hours ( users from database **visits** )?

Comment: So you want a query the will return a result for people in the `users` table minus the people in the `visits` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't mean "from one database [...] which are in second database", they're just in different tables, but in the same database :)

Anywho, something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id NOT IN 
(SELECT userID FROM visits WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 HOUR))
```

or something like that :)

Comment: omg, i wrote database.. i meant table :) edited now, thanks for the query, i think that is what i wanted

Comment: If it was, feel free to flag it as the answer.

Comment: i have to wait 2 mins ) "You can accept an answer in 2 minutes"